# Android Jetpack Navigation storing deepLink as constants

Tags: android, xml, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

The Android documentation recommends using deep links for inter-module navigation. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-multi-module#across

Note the deeplink with the following:

```
app:uri="android-app://example.google.app/fragment_two"
```

The same url is then referenced in code:

```
val request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
    .fromUri("android-app://example.google.app/fragment_two".toUri())
    .build()
```

The example is clear, but it uses hard-coded strings, which should best be stored in one location. I could use a string resource, like this:

```
// values/strings.xml
<string name="fragment_two_url">android-app://example.google.app/fragment_two/</string>

// nav_graph.xml
app:uri="@string/fragment_two_url"

// Kotlin code
val request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
    .fromUri(context.getString(R.string.fragment_two_url))
    .build()
```

however this won't work if the deep link has arguments, like this:

```
app:uri="android-app://example.google.app/fragment_two/{arg}"
```

We cannot insert the string resource like we did above.

```
// This won't work
app:uri="@string/fragment_two_url/{arg}"
```

Is there a way to create a constant that could easily be referenced in **both** the Kotlin code and navigation graph XML?

Comment: did u find a decision? i have the same problem :/

Comment: @Sawyerhard Unfortunately, no. We decided that it's fine to leave it like that for now and hopefully we'll soon no longer need that once we've fully migrated to Compose.

Answer (score -1):

> see the following from [Format and style](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling)

```
<string name="url_with_args">android-app://example.google.app/fragment_two/%s</string>
```

> and then use it like this:

val finalUrl = context.getString(R.string.url_with_args, "Your_Argument")

Comment: I see I didn't make it clear enough, I edited my answer now. The problem is not so much with the Kotlin code, as it is with the navigation graph.